# Sub-process (?) management

Tags: python, kivy, timing

I am currently working on a project that requires a process to be run at all times in the background that will output data via serial interface and there can only be one of these processes active at a time. We need to create a touch screen interface to control this process in regards to sample rate and some other factors. The problem that I am having is how to manage this process. This is being ran on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and the touch screen is using kivy. Since i need to manage this from the touch screen i need some sort of access to this background process to change out values because if i were to run it in the UI the touch screen would freeze because i would have to throw the read into a while true loop which would never exit. An example of how the serial output process is formatted is

```
percent = calculate_percentage(data_rate, max_value)
while True:
    percent.output_percentage()
    time.sleep((1/data_rate) - 0.00055)
```

The 0.00055 is about how long the percent.output_percentage() takes to run since we want as accurate of a sample rate as possible and without taking this value into consideration we get a large amount of drift the longer the process runs. If anyone has any suggestions on how to take care of that as well i would love to hear them.

I would love to find some way to manage this process and easily change out values and kill the old process.

Comment: There is alternatives to two processes. You can hook the serial communication into the kivy mainloop.

Comment: You could try to use multiprocessing and specifically Queue to achieve passing messages back and forth between processes. So the UI process should start your background process and then send signals to it

Comment: Another very simple and crude solution is to have a settings file with params that are periodically polled by your background task, and can be modified by your UI process

Comment: I think the settings file would work decently, the only problem i see is that i need to display the number generated in the background processes to the UI. I guess i could add it to the settings file as well but that might make it more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: The obvious solutions is probably to put the subprocess loop in a separate thread.